# Cannot Convert from error in simple class structure

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have the following class relationships

```
    public interface ICapability
    {
    }

    public interface IBaseService<T> where T : ICapability
    {
    }

    public abstract class BaseService<out T> : IBaseService<T> where T : ICapability
    {
       // modified...
       T MapEventToCapability(dynamic eventData, T capability);
    }

    public class SomeCapability : ICapability
    {
    }

    public partial class Service1 : BaseService<SomeCapability>
    {
        public Service1()
        {
        }
    }

    public class ServiceResolver 
    {
        public void Register(BaseService<ICapability> serviceToRegister)
        {
        }
    }
```

I try to invoke the Register method, passing in a new service1 as shown:

```
var b = new ServiceResolver();
var c = new Service1();

b.Register(c);
```

However I get a compile time error on c in the call to Register as follows;

```
Cannot convert Service1 to BaseService<ICapability>
```

I assumed that because Service1 is of type BaseService and that since SomeCapability is of type ICapability that this wouldn't be an issue.

I tried casting to BaseService as well I tried changing the input parameter on Register to be an IBaseService and again casting but then I get a runtime error.

Comment: "Covariance" is the word you want to google

Comment: Why do you need to pass a capability in if it is being passed out in that added method?

Comment: to be clear if the method was `T MapEventToCapability(dynamic eventData)` it would work just fine as that is only going out not in.

Comment: @jamiec,  I was able to refactor so as to remove T as only out.  Thank you once again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the question has been updated since this answer was posted - covariance is no longer an option having added a method which is incompatible

---

You'll need to do 2 things to make this work

1. Make `Register` take `IBaseService<ICapability>` not `BaseService<ICapability>`
2. Make `IBaseService` covariant by marking the generic type as `out` - this is the same as the reason you can pass a `List<Foo>` to a merthod which expects an `IEnumerable<Foo>` as `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in a similar manner.

---

```
public class ServiceResolver
{
    public void Register(IBaseService<ICapability> serviceToRegister)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface IBaseService<out T>
    where T : ICapability
{
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O0yXa5

Comment: Thank you Jamiec,  that has resolved my issue

Comment: @JohnKears great glad I could help!

Comment: I ran into one other small issue, note that I updated the IBaseService interface, added the line T MapEventToCapability(dynamic eventData, T capability);  (see original post) That shows another error,  'The parameter 'T' must be contravariantly ...

Comment: @JohnKears yep, you now have a catch-22. If you want covariance you cant pass an instance in, hence the `out` modifier on the generic type. (I thought this might happen, but could only answer given the information present in the question)

Comment: thank you nonetheless. I should have been more explicit in my original post, I was trying not to over-clutter the question.  Thank you for your assistance, as I did learn something new.  I marked your response as the Answer. Cheers!